# RippleAPI Prepare Payment Paths object

Tags: transactions, ripple, ripple-api

When using [ripple API Prepare Payment method](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-rest#prepare-payment).

```
GET /v1/accounts/{:source_address}/payments/paths/{:destination_address}/{:amount}
```

I am struggling with how should I understand `paths` part of response?

```
"paths": "[[{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"issuer\":\"rMwjYedjc7qqtKYVLiAccJSmCwih4LnE2q\",\"type\":48,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000030\"},{\"account\":\"rMwjYedjc7qqtKYVLiAccJSmCwih4LnE2q\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"}],[{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"issuer\":\"rpDMez6pm6dBve2TJsmDpv7Yae6V5Pyvy2\",\"type\":48,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000030\"},{\"account\":\"rpDMez6pm6dBve2TJsmDpv7Yae6V5Pyvy2\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"},{\"account\":\"rHAwwozJw6FHfnJfRQaFXrkGHocGoaNYSy\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"},{\"account\":\"rMwjYedjc7qqtKYVLiAccJSmCwih4LnE2q\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"}],[{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"issuer\":\"rsP3mgGb2tcYUrxiLFiHJiQXhsziegtwBc\",\"type\":48,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000030\"},{\"account\":\"rsP3mgGb2tcYUrxiLFiHJiQXhsziegtwBc\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"},{\"account\":\"rEtr3Kzh5MmhPbeNu6PDtQZsKBpgFEEEo5\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"},{\"account\":\"rMwjYedjc7qqtKYVLiAccJSmCwih4LnE2q\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"}],[{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"issuer\":\"rsP3mgGb2tcYUrxiLFiHJiQXhsziegtwBc\",\"type\":48,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000030\"},{\"account\":\"rsP3mgGb2tcYUrxiLFiHJiQXhsziegtwBc\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"},{\"account\":\"rKvPTQrD8ap1Y8TSmKjcK6G7q7Kvx7RAqQ\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"},{\"account\":\"rMwjYedjc7qqtKYVLiAccJSmCwih4LnE2q\",\"type\":1,\"type_hex\":\"0000000000000001\"}]]",
```

I know how to read JSON and understand that currencies are being transferred between accounts, what I don't get is in what order? from which to which in what amounts and currencies?

Also what does `type` stand for (1 or 48 in example), where can I get list of all types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `type` is a bitfield, defined by [the following C++ code](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/4cbbacc946affa5a99b2fe28224ed6bee5b92a90/src/ripple/protocol/STPathSet.h#L34):

```
class STPathElement
{
public:
    enum Type
    {
        typeNone        = 0x00,
        typeAccount     = 0x01, // Rippling through an account (vs taking an offer).
        typeCurrency    = 0x10, // Currency follows.
        typeIssuer      = 0x20, // Issuer follows.
        typeBoundary    = 0xFF, // Boundary between alternate paths.
        typeAll = typeAccount | typeCurrency | typeIssuer,
                                // Combination of all types.
    };
[snipped]
```

So 48 (or 0x30) would mean that `typeCurrency` and `typeAccount` are both set. I think this means that it's currency issued by someone.

1 (0x01) means `typeAccount` is set. I think this means that it's an account that contains XRP.

As for the rest of it, I have no clue.